# How do I make a button that makes a custom backgroundimage of choice?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I am trying to make a button that opens an openFileDialog, then when chosen a png, a jpeg, or a jpg, it will make that into the backgroundimage?

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if  (Functions.newbackground.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {

                string MainText = File.ReadAllText(Functions.openfiledialog.FileName);
                this.BackgroundImage = MainText;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

And in the Functions.cs, i put

```
public static OpenFileDialog newbackground = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        Filter = "Picture (*.png)|*.png",
        FilterIndex = 1,
        RestoreDirectory = true,
        Title = "Project Teal (Sirius)"
    };
```

Comment: `BackgroundImage` is an Image object, not text. If you want to lock the file on disc, use the Bitmap constructor that takes a file path and a `bool` (set to `true`). Otherwise `BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Functions.openfiledialog.FileName)))`

Comment: `BackgroundImage  = new Bitmap(FileName)`